# rotate large table ajax

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very large table (that overflows the content div) and because it's dynamic it can contain at least 20 columns. 
Anyway, the problem is that I'm obliged to put this table in a "tight" div.
And, the idea is to avoid the overflow and, to display elegantly all the columns so that it can rotate horizontally (a slide from left to right and possibly with "previous" and "forward" buttons).

Is there a ready script to help developping that?

Thank you very much,
Regards.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by "rotate".

Comment: The post was edited to clarify the "rotate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it up so that it can be scrolled horizontally within the alloted div:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto">
  <table> [ really wide table data ] </table>
</div>
```

This would result in the table to be contained in a horizontally scrollable div. It would only look good if the table is not taller vertically than the window height (that  is it can fit in the window vertically without needing to be scrolled)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, how can i remove the horizontal scrollbar and add an effect that make the content "scrolling" and rotating automatically like the rotate function of the jquery framework?